# procedure to migrate AWS instance from one region to another region via console

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ami, amazon-ec2

I'm new to amazon web services. In RDS dashboard its showing one instance in US west(oregon) and in EC2 dashboard showing as running 2 instance in US west 2b and 2c respectively. Now what i want is first i need to know the difference between RDS dashboard and EC2 instance and i need to migrate these instance to another region to Asia pacific(Singapore) with all of the data which i'm having in US west(oregon).
Some one please tell me the step by step procedure. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/800ci.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RDS is managed database servers. EC2 is your virtual servers. I really suggest reading and learning a little about AWS before trying to use it.

You will need to take snapshots of your RDS servers and your EC2 EBS volumes. Then you will need to copy those snapshots to the new region. Then you can create new instances in the new region from those snapshots. Finally you can delete the old instances in the old region once you are done with them.

You will also need to create a similar AWS environment in the new region by recreating the same VPC configuration, security groups, database parameter groups, CloudWatch alerts, SNS topics, etc.